# How to contribute for pgrouting.org

Tags: algorithm

I wanna to contribute for algorithms, that's why i chose pgrouting can anyone help me out and suggest me more organisations to which i can contribute.
Thnks.

Comment: Can you expand on your question a bit more, as it stands this is not a good question for StackExchange. Please check the [FAQ](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq) on best types of questions to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Are you wondering how to contribute to pgrouting, or are you looking for similar projects to contribute to?

- To contribute to PgRouting i would suggest their [dev maling list](http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/pgrouting-dev)
- for other projects your question is a bit broad, there are a multitude of open source projects, but since you're interested in routing and algorithms then maybe these projects are of interest:

  - [GraphHopper](http://graphhopper.com) (java)
  - [OpenSourceRouting Machine](http://project-osrm.org/) (c/c++)